# Are C++ smart pointers lockfree?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, smart-pointers, lock-free

Are the following operations lockfree for `std::unique_ptr` and/or `std::shared_ptr`?

1. Dereferencing, i.e. `read(*myPtr)` or `myPtr->getSomething()`
2. Removing a reference, i.e. with `std::move(myUniquePtr)` or when a `std::shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

In my case, I am not concurrently accessing these pointers from multiple threads. I'm just curious if I can use them exclusively on a high-priority, lockfree thread. The objects managed by the pointers were allocated by the main thread prior to the high-priority callbacks and will not be deallocated until the callbacks cease.

Thanks!

Comment: use these http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

Comment: Note that `move` and going out of scooe are **very** different.  `move` *never* changes the reference count.

Comment: @bryanchen those are for multiple threads one variable, which is not what the OP is talking about methinks.

Comment: @Yakk doesn't `move` remove the reference from a source `unique_ptr` and add it to a destination `unique_ptr`? I've seen `std::remove_reference` in errors related to moving a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @mxdubois sure, bit `unique_ptr` has no need to ever lock: it has no significant contention.  For `shared`, you can move the reference to the dest without doing a +1 -1 mess...  without messimg with the control block comtents of the source at all!  The dest admittedly needs a `.reset()` of non-empty, so there is that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that the standard says is that for `shared_ptr<>` (20.7.2.2/4 "Class template shared_ptr"):

> Changes in `use_count()` do not reflect modifications that can
>   introduce data races

It doesn't say that those changes in `use_count()` have to be lock free.  The standard permits a mutex to be used to prevent the data race.

`unique_ptr<>` has no promises to prevent data races (it's not intended to be thread safe on it's own).

Comment: In practice, however...  about the only one with any reason to lock is 'going out of scope'.

Comment: @mxdubois: I don't think there's any reason for the `unique_ptr` implementation to introduce a lock for dereferencing, but I'm not sure the standard forbids it. Similarly for the move operation.

Comment: It isn't guaranteed to be lockfree, but there's no reason to use an implementation that synchronises at all.

Answer (score 5):

With a reasonable implementation, you can assume:

**std::unique_ptr**:

- All operations on a std::unique_ptr are as lock-free as the corresponding operations on a raw pointer, because there is nothing special regarding concurrency.

**std::shared_ptr**:

- All operations, that do not change the reference count, are as lock-free as the corresponding operations on a raw pointer. That includes the operations *dereferencing* and *move construction*.
- std::move is lock-free, because it is only a cast to an rvalue-reference.
- The destructor of a std::shared_ptr is at least as lock-free as `std::atomic<std::size_t>` (can be checked with the member function `is_lock_free`).
- *Move assignment* depends on whether the std::shared_ptr on the left side has an associated managed object or not. If there is an associated managed object, it is as lock-free as the *destructor*. Otherwise it is as lock-free as a *move constructor*, because the reference count is not changed.

Comment: I'm going to accept Burr's answer because I was mostly looking for what was guaranteed, but thanks for the extra info!